# Not able to perform boolean operation in ansys design modular

Tags: ansys

I am performing a steady state thermal simulation my model consist of a composite having circular particles embedded inside a large circular domain. see image attached. Now I am importing a cad model having those random small dispersed circles.

After this in ansys I am sketching the larger circular domain and then using surfaces from sketches I am generating the bigger circle.

Then I am using boolean operation to separate those small circles from the large circle as both of them have different properties.

But the problem is that at Higher area fractions of small circle the operation is showing this error ("Error: Operation would result in non-manifold bodies
Context: Geometry Engine, while generating Feature Boolean1")

This is due to small distance between neighbouring particles. How can I troubleshoot this error as I am not able to identify the particle causing this as I have many composite of same area fraction but only some are causing this trouble.

If I am able to identify the close one causing problem may be I can reduce their diameter. Also How can I perform this in design modular reducing the diameter operation??[image]

Some method to rectify this error without changing the diameter by identifiying the particle causing the problem. If it is necessary to change the diameter tell me how to do it in design modular ?